# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded...etc. Error goes away on refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

[image]

This question seems like duplicate but it's not. I understand the error and have solved such error number of time but this time I couldn't figure out what's causing infinite loop.

here is code for react component causing the error:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './Login.scss';
import axios from 'axios';
import { endPoint } from '../App/path';
import { logIn, isLoggedIn } from '../App/TokenStore';

const re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,15}$/;
class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      errorMessage: 'Please Login to proceed!',
    };
  }

  onUserNameChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ username: e.target.value });
  }

  onPasswordChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
  }

  onFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    const { history } = this.props;

    const isUserNameValid = re.test(String(username).toLowerCase());
    if (isUserNameValid) {
      axios.post(`${endPoint}/login.json`, { username, password })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            if (response.statusText === 'OK') {
              this.setState({
                username: '', password: '', errorMessage: '',
              });
              if (response.config.data) {
                console.log(response);
                logIn(response.config.data, 'response.config.data.password');
                history.push('/dashboard');
              } else {
                throw new Error();
              }
            } else {
              this.setState({ errorMessage: 'Please enter valid credential!' });
            }
          }
        }).catch((err) => {
          if (err.response) {
            this.setState({ errorMessage: 'Please enter valid username!' });
          } else {
            this.setState({ errorMessage: 'Unknown Error!!' });
          }
        });
    } else {
      this.setState({ errorMessage: 'Please enter valid username!' });
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (isLoggedIn()) {
      return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
    }
    const {
      username, password, errorMessage,
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="Login">
        <form className="Form" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
          <p className="errorMessage">{errorMessage}</p>
          <div className="form__group">
            <label id="username" className="Label" htmlFor="username">
              <i className="fa fa-user" />
              <b>Username</b>
            </label>
            <input
              value={username}
              onChange={e => this.onUserNameChange(e)}
              id="username"
              type="username"
              placeholder="Your username"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form__group">
            <label id="password" className="Label" htmlFor="password">
              <i className="fa fa-key" />
              <b>Password</b>
            </label>
            <input
              value={password}
              onChange={e => this.onPasswordChange(e)}
              id="password"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Your Password"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="Btn">LOGIN</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


Login.propTypes = {
  history: PropTypes.shape(),
};
Login.defaultProps = { history: {} };

export default Login;
```

**these are the other function I am using in the above component:**

```
export const logIn = (username, token) => {
  sessionStorage.setItem('username', username);
  sessionStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true);
  sessionStorage.setItem('token', token);
};

export const isLoggedIn = () => Boolean(sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn'));
```

here is dashboard component

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Dashboard.scss';

const dashboard = () => (
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="card col-5 mr-auto ml-auto">
        <h5 className="card-header">Lorem ipsum</h5>
        <div className="card-body">
          <h5 className="card-title">Lorem ipsum</h5>
          <p className="card-text">Lorem ipsum</p>
          <NavLink to="/dashboard/VRlist" className="btn btn-dashboard">Update/Delete</NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="card col-5 mr-auto ml-auto">
        <h5 className="card-header">Lorem ipsum</h5>
        <div className="card-body">
          <h5 className="card-title">Lorem ipsum</h5>
          <p className="card-text">Lorem ipsum</p>
          <NavLink to="/dashboard/registration" className="btn btn-dashboard"> Registration</NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default dashboard;
```

here is my main app component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './Navbar/Navbar';
import Login from './Login/Login';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard/Dashboard';
import { isLoggedIn } from './App/TokenStore';
import VRlist from './VRlist/VRlist';
import NewRegistration from './newRegistration/newRegistration';
import UpdateRegistration from './updateRegistration/updateRegistration';

const App = () => {
  if (!isLoggedIn()) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Route component={Login} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/VRlist/edit/:id" component={UpdateRegistration} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/VRlist" component={VRlist} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/registration" component={NewRegistration} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Now when I run the application and do login, this error will happen only for the first time login in the current tab, if I refresh the page the error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I've used react-router and react-router-dom version 5, that's what was causing an infinite render loop while calling an history.push(), however for the rest of the components 'history.push()' was working fine but login page. Though switching over to version 4.3.1 emitted issue completely.